# vue ts type for current instance

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-tsc

I keep getting a ts error type:

**Propery Instance does not exist on HTMLElement.** I get my element in query selector and then in onmounted I access _instance. what type should I use to stop getting this error?

```
onMounted(() => {
  const myEl = document.querySelector('myHTMLElement') as HTMLElement

  nextTick(() => {
    if (myEl!== null)
      myEl._instance.exposed(someValue)
  })
})
```

the error is on   myEl.**_instance**.exposed(someValue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript is correct: `_instance` does not exist on [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) interface.

If you have reason to believe it should exist in this particular case, you have to let TS in on the secret:

```
interface SomeElement extends HTMLElement {
  _instance: {
    // update if you want type checking on arg0:
    exposed: (arg0: unknown) => void
  }
}

onMounted(() => {
  const myEl: SomeElement | null = document.querySelector("some-element")

  nextTick(() => {
    myEl?._instance.exposed(someValue)
  })
})
```

Side note: you should **not** use `document.querySelector` in a Vue app. Use [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) instead.